# Do not show results if directory is empty using Bash

Tags: bash, shell

For example, try following command in an empty directory:

```
$ for i in *; do echo $i; done
*
```

Is there a way to suppress the printout of `*`?

Answer (score 5):

Set [nullglob](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob)

```
shopt -s nullglob
for i in *; do echo "$i"; done
```

Comment: You have forgot to quote ``"$i"``

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea is use ls command, but if filename has space, `ls` will split file name by space. In order to handle space in filename, you can do like this:

```
ls|while read i; do echo $i; done
```

Aleks-Daniel Jakimenko said "Do not parse ls". Which is good, so how about this if we don't want to change nullglob:

```
for i in *; do  [ -e "$i" ] && echo $i; done
```

Comment: This will not handle newline in file name, just being paranoid ;-)

Answer (score -1):

To avoid the `*`, you can try something like

```
for i in `ls`; do echo $i; done
```

Tried now on an empty directory, no output given...